# Check multiple URL'S path extensions

Tags: c#

I have the following code that checks a particular column in SQL and determines whether it is a image or a document that works fine. The column, in this code is Addon10. However, I would like to expand on that where it will check if the column has multiple images in it.

Currently, the images are stored as followed:

```
<img src="/images/pt1.png" style="width: 100%;">
<img src="/images/pt2.png" style="width: 100%;">
<img src="/images/pt3.png" style="width: 100%;">
<img src="/images/pt4.png" style="width: 100%;">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<%
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty("Addon10")){
    string grabExt = "Addon10".Substring("Addon10".LastIndexOf(".") + 1).ToLower().Remove(3);
    if (grabExt == "png" || grabExt == "jpg" || grabExt == "jpeg" || grabExt == "tif" || grabExt == "tiff" || grabExt == "gif" || grabExt == "bmp")
         Response.Write("<div style='page-break-before:always'>" + "Addon10" + "</div>");
    else{
       if (grabExt == "txt" || grabExt == "docx" || grabExt =="doc" || grabExt == "pdf" || grabExt== "rtf" || grabExt == ".xls" || grabExt == ".xlr" || grabExt == ".xlsx" || grabExt == "ods" || grabExt == "asp" || grabExt == "aspx")
         Response.Write("<div style='page-break-before:always'>" + "Addon10" + "</div>");
    }
}
%>
```

@Brad I did the following:

```
<% string fileListString = "Addon10"; 
fileListString = fileListString.Replace("<img src=", ">|<img src="); 
string[] arrTest = fileListString.Split('|');
   foreach (string s in arrTest)
   {
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty("Addon10")){
        string grabExt = "Addon10".Substring("Addon10".LastIndexOf(".") + 1).ToLower().Remove(3);
        if (grabExt == "png" || grabExt == "jpg" || grabExt == "jpeg" || grabExt == "tif" || grabExt == "tiff" || grabExt == "gif" || grabExt == "bmp")
           Response.Write("<div style='page-break-before:always'>" + "Addon10" + "</div>");
     else{
       if (grabExt == "txt" || grabExt == "docx" || grabExt =="doc" || grabExt == "pdf" || grabExt== "rtf" || grabExt == ".xls" || grabExt == ".xlr" || grabExt == ".xlsx" || grabExt == "ods" || grabExt == "asp" || grabExt == "aspx")
             Response.Write("<div style='page-break-before:always'>" + "Addon10" + "</div>");
    }
  }
}
%>
```

Comment: Do you have multiple images stored as 1 string in SQL?  I would suggest you not store more then 1 record/image in a string in SQL, have  multiple records, one for each image

Comment: @Brad: Right but the problem is that a row within that column can contain more then one image/document

Comment: @Brad: Yes, multiple images stored as a 1 string in SQL. I agree not to store more than 1 record but based on my understanding, thats how they are storing the record with multiple images/documents.

Comment: and they are stored with the image tags and width?  If so you can do a count on the occurance of the <img src=  text, and if the count is > 1 then there is more then 1.  Then you would have to parse it out and do a loop (or just parse it out and loop through anyway, if there is only 1 it would just loop once)

Comment: @Brad: At times, they are stored with the image tags and width. However, there are times that they are just pdf files and so on. That is why I believe your suggestion would work but only when the image tag is used. To count the occurrences of the img tag, how would I do that in C#. I know in javascript, I could do the getElementsByTagName but in C#, not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Regular Expression to test for multiple images in tags in a column:

```
var imageExtensions = new[] {   "png",  "jpg",  "jpeg",  "tif",  "tiff",  "gif",  "bmp" };
var imageExtPattern = String.Join("|", imageExtensions);
var multiImagePattern = $"(^<img src=\"[^.]+\\.(?:{imageExtPattern})\".*>$)+";

var hasMultiImages = Regex.IsMatch(Addon10, multiImagePattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 1):

NOTE:  I know this is not the the best solution!  It can give you an idea.  (the best solution is to not store the data like that in the table but store each image/link as their own records).

It may work but may not work at all depending on if your data is not consistant, but it does work in the example below.

```
// NOTE:  in my string for testing there are double quotes in there and those are for escape characters.
// populate your string of files into a string variable
            string fileListString = @"<img src=/""/images/pt1.png/"" style=/""width: 100%;/""><img src=/""/images/pt2.png/"" style=/""width: 100%;/""><img src=/""/images/pt3.png/"" style=/""width: 100%;/""><img src=/""/images/pt4.png/"" style=/""width: 100%;/"">";

            // replace the closing HTML tag and Opening of the next img tag with a pipe (or you can change this to use a different delimiter
            fileListString = fileListString.Replace("><img src=", ">|<img src=");

            // then split the string on the pipe delimiter
            string[] arrTest = fileListString.Split('|');

            // then loop through each option
            foreach (string s in arrTest)
            {
                // do your IF logic here
            }
```

Comment: @ Brad: Thank you. This does give me an idea

Comment: No problem, as I said this is not ideal, and depending on your data if it is not standardized (same format every time) could not work, but like I said give you some where to start.

Comment: @ Brad: For your code, it will repeat the image twice. My guess is do to the Replace statement.

Comment: Im not seeing where it is duplicating the images.  I run my above code and my arrTest array has 4 values, one for each image.

Comment: @ Brad: I posted what I did.

Comment: in your replace you have: "<img src=", ">|<img src=", it needs to be: "><img src=", ">|<img src=". You are missing the first character in my example of the ">", thats why your getting duplicates.  This makes sure it has a closing and then opening tag (so if there is only 1 image it wont actually do the replace)

Comment: @ Brad: Thank you for that, I completely miss that. I notice if I just add my code within your for loop, it is still not comparing each record.

Comment: @ Brad: Instead, it repeats the images. So it is comparing but I am having a hard time to grab the extensions from the array

Comment: @ Brad: Thanks. I was able to figure it out. Thank you